# How to vgscan in RHEL 5.8 rescue mode?

Tags: rhel

I want to increase the journaling size of an EXT3 FS: /var. 
I booted up a RHEL 5.8 DVD, and tried the "linux rescue" mode. 
The problem is that the original install that has the mentioned /var FS is in a vg/lvm. So I tried the command:

```
vgscan
```

as ex.: this howto states it: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_installation/rhel_6_installation_ap-rescuemode.html

but the vgscan binary is not found. I tried to find it with "find / -name vgscan", but it didn't find it.

**Q: What am I missing? Isn't the rescue mode for RESCUING??**

Comment: There are much better distros for "live" system maintenance. My personal favorite is [grml](http://grml.org/).

Comment: Maybe there's a `lvm` command in which case you'd do `lvm vgscan`. See also `vgs` or `lvm vgs`. And `vgchange -ay` or `lvm vgchange -ay`.

Answer (score 1):

Commands like `vgscan`, `pvscan`, `vgs` are actually synonyms/shortcuts for `lvm vgscan`, `lvm pvscan`, `lvm vgs` respectively.

The RHEL 5 rescue environments as I recall did not include the synonyms.  As an additional note, the volume groups may have already been activated, you can check this by looking at the output of `ls -l /dev/mapper` with in the rescue environment.

Comment: You can also just type in lvm to get into an interactive lvm prompt, and then work with the lvm commands.